# Integrate PWA in ReactJs and Angular App?

Tags: reactjs, angular

I have an website which is in Angular but on clicking a button in website, it redirects to another website which is developed in ReactJs. I have individually Integrated PWA in reactJs and angular. But is it possible we can make PWA in such website where 2 technologies are being used?

Answer (score 0):

I guess not cause these are 2 separate applications, not one ...